# Python: Determine when more than one bit has changed in a nested list

Tags: python, list

Basically I have a list that goes like this:

```
[(0, 0, 1), 1]
[(0, 1, 0), 1]
[(0, 1, 0), 1]
[(0, 1, 1), 0]
[(0, 1, 1), 0]
[(1, 0, 0), 0]
[(1, 0, 0), 0]
[(1, 0, 1), 0]
[(1, 0, 1), 0]
[(1, 1, 0), 0]
[(1, 1, 0), 0]
```

And I want to compare the first element of the list with the next. If one of the elements has changed more than one bit, for example `list[2]` to `list[3]`, i want my code to return both. I cant figure it out how to do it.

Comment: Can you please update your question and put there expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task of determining if more than one bit has changed can be done by:

1. Calculating the `XOR` of value 1 and value 2.
2. If the `XOR` of the values is *not* a power of two, more than one bit has been changed, e.g. `(x & (x - 1))`, where the `XOR` value is `x`.

For example:

```
for idx, (b1, b2) in enumerate(zip(data, data[1:])):
    a = int(''.join(map(str, (*b1[0], b1[1]))), 2)
    b = int(''.join(map(str, (*b2[0], b2[1]))), 2)
    if (a ^ b) & ((a ^ b) - 1):
        print(f'Change in index {idx} and {idx+1}', b1, b2)
```

gives the following output:

```
Change in index 0 and 1 [(0, 0, 1), 1] [(0, 1, 0), 1]
Change in index 2 and 3 [(0, 1, 0), 1] [(0, 1, 1), 0]
Change in index 4 and 5 [(0, 1, 1), 0] [(1, 0, 0), 0]
Change in index 8 and 9 [(1, 0, 1), 0] [(1, 1, 0), 0]
```

Comments:

This operation was made tricky by the fact of the first set of bits are nested within a tuple, and the final bit is not. This is the reason for the 'ridiculous' derivation of the `a` and `b` variables, to convert the nested bits into a base-2 integer value.

---

#### Edit:

Added additional logic to address the comment:

> If I want to see if only *one* bit changed what I should do?

The logic is very similar, however has a key difference as the result of a single change and a non-change (using `x & (x-1)`) have the same value: 0. Therefore we must:

1. Test a change *has* occurred.
2. Verify the change has only affected a single bit.

For example:

```
for idx, (b1, b2) in enumerate(zip(data, data[1:])):
    a = int(''.join(map(str, (*b1[0], b1[1]))), 2)
    b = int(''.join(map(str, (*b2[0], b2[1]))), 2)
    xor = a ^ b
    if (xor) and not (xor & (xor - 1)):
        print(f'Change in index {idx} and {idx+1}', b1, b2)
```

The statement `if (xor) and not (xor & (xor - 1))` tests there *was* a change (`xor`) (using [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)) and the change affects only a single bit (`not (xor & (xor - 1))`).

Output:

```
Change in index 6 and 7 [(1, 0, 0), 0] [(1, 0, 1), 0]
```

Comment: That's it, thank you. Just to explain what is the purpose of this, basically im trying to make an algoritihm to find propagation delays base on a truth table, and make a PWL for a spice archive.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it’s working for you.

Comment: If i want to see if only one bit changed what I should do?

Comment: @ArturCorreia - There you go mate. Updated the answer to address your question.